# Powershell wildcard for path with different language in Windows\System32\ Folder

Tags: powershell

The original location to run the cscript is here for en-US Windows devices:

`cscript "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prndrvr.vbs"`

What I need is to allow any other languages where xx-xx could be en-US, en-GB, de-DE, nl-NL, etc

`"C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\xx-xx\Prndrvr.vbs"`

I've tried using `*` in different ways but I guess I'm not getting the right combo.

The script is executing the .vbs file to install the printer.

Thanks!

Comment: So when there are multiple language version available, which one do you want to pick?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Any en-US, en-GB, de-DE, nl-NL, etc.

Comment: Okay, so the script should just pick 1 at random? Or you want to execute all of them?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen  It should be able to use the Prndrvr.vbs regardless of the folder name. If the user has Netherlands selected in Windows for system language initially it will be nl-NL. They will all be running this same script.

Answer (score 1):

Start by seeing if you can locate the version that corresponds to the current UI locale:

```
$UIlocale = Get-UICulture
$localizedPath = 'C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\{0}\Prndrvr.vbs' -f $UIlocale.Name

if(Test-Path $localizedPath){
  & cscript $localizedPath
}
elseif(Test-Path 'C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prndrvr.vbs') {
  # fallback to en-US version
  & cscript 'C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\Prndrvr.vbs'
}
else {
  # attempt to find _any_ version of the script, select the first one found
  $printScript = Get-ChildItem -Path 'C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\??-??\*' -Filter Prndrvr.vbs |Select -First 1
  if($printScript){
    & cscript $printScript.FullName
  }
  else {
    Write-Error "Unable to locate print management script!"
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is a lot more scalable. I just needed something quick.

Answer (score 0):

I did something different.

I created a variable before the command runs declared as `$Printerscript`

Then I used `Resolve-Path` so it looks something like:

`$PrndrvrVBS = Resolve-Path "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\*\Prndrvr.vbs"`

So the final outcome is

```
#VBScript Prndrvr Path
$PrndrvrVBS = Resolve-Path "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\*\Prndrvr.vbs" 

cscript "$PrndrvrVBS"
```

Comment: You probably want to do `Resolve-Path "C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\*\Prndrvr.vbs" |Select -First 1` in case it resolves _multiple_ versions